# Operation time out and list view threshold issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, onedrive

I have this script that I got from Online but I'm just wondering how can I improve/modify the code so that I'll not get operation timeout and listview threshold issue.

Right now the script is working fine but sometime I got operation timeout and listview threshold issue and it stop working.

This script is basically deleting a very large OneDrive Busines folder

```
#Variables

      $SiteURL = "https://companyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_gm_com"
     $ServerRelativeUrl= "Documents/PC-OFFBOARD-0257/C$/Apps/matlab2017a/help"

      Write-host  $ServerRelativeUrl

        
    Try {
        #Get Credentials to connect
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Global:adminUPN, $Global:adminPwd)
        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
    
        #Get the web from URL
        $Web = $Ctx.web
        $Ctx.Load($Web)
        $Ctx.executeQuery()


    
        #Get the Folder object by Server Relative URL
        $Folder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($ServerRelativeUrl)
        $Ctx.Load($Folder)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
        #Call the function to empty Folder
        Empty-SPOFolder $Folder
    
        #Delete the given Folder itself
        Write-host  -f Green "Deleting Folder:"$Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
        $Folder.Recycle() | Out-Null
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
    }


    
    #Function to Delete all files and Sub-folders of a given Folder
    Function Empty-SPOFolder([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$Folder)
    {
        Try {
            #Process all Sub Folders of the given folder
            $SubFolders = $Folder.Folders
            $Ctx.Load($SubFolders)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            
            #Empty all subfolders
            Foreach($Folder in $SubFolders)
            {
                #Exclude "Forms" and Hidden folders
                    Empty-Folder -Folder $Folder
                
            }

            #delete all subfolders
            Foreach($Folder in $SubFolders)
            {
                #Exclude "Forms" and Hidden folders
            
                    #Call the function recursively to empty the folder
                    Empty-SPOFolder -Folder $Folder
    
                    #Delete the folder
                    Write-Host -f Green "$Folder.UniqueId"
                    #$Ctx.Web.GetFolderById($Folder.UniqueId).Recycle() | Out-Null
                    $Ctx.Web.GetFolderById($Folder.UniqueId).DeleteObject() | Out-Null
                    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                    Write-host  -f Green "Deleted Folder:"$Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
                
            }
            #Empty the root folder
            Empty-Folder -Folder $Folder
            $Ctx = $Folder.Context
            $Files = $Folder.Files
            $Ctx.Load($Files)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
            #Iterate through each File in the Root folder
            Foreach($File in $Files)
            {
                #Delete the file
                Write-Host -f Green "$File.Name"
                $Folder.Files.GetByUrl($File.ServerRelativeUrl).Recycle() | Out-Null
                $Folder.Files.GetByUrl($File.ServerRelativeUrl).DeleteObject() | Out-Null
                Write-host -f Green "Deleted File '$($File.Name)' from '$($File.ServerRelativeURL)'"
            }
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error: $Folder.UniqueId - $File.Name " $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }

    #Function to Delete all files from a folder
    Function Empty-Folder([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$Folder)
    {
        Try {
            #Get All Files from the Folder
            $Ctx = $Folder.Context
            $Files = $Folder.Files
            $Ctx.Load($Files)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
            #Iterate through each File in the Root folder
            Foreach($File in $Files)
            {
                #Delete the file
                Write-Host -f Green "$File.Name"
        
                $Folder.Files.GetByUrl($File.ServerRelativeUrl).DeleteObject() | Out-Null
                Write-host -f Green "Deleted File '$($File.Name)' from '$($File.ServerRelativeURL)'"
            }
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error: $Folder.UniqueId - $File.Name " $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
```

```
Error: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder.UniqueId - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.Name  Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out."
Error: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder.UniqueId - .Name  Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."
Error: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder.UniqueId - .Name  Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."
```

Comment: You need to use different variables in your `Empty-SPOFolder` function. As parameter you give it `$Folder`, then you iterate its subfolders using that same `$Folder` variable, thus overwriting it but later you are using it again as if it has not changed from being the rootfolder... Solution": change the `$Folder` variable to `$SubDir` or something in both `foreach()` loops there. Also, PowerShell parses and executes code from top to bottom, so your functions should come **on top** of the main routine.

Comment: Hi..Theo I'm little bit confused so can you please show me and answer it below pls.

Comment: but I'm still wondering how that would solve my exceeds List view threshold issue?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you are using the same variable `$Folder` for both the rootfolder and its sub directories. By iterating using that same variable, you will no longer have the rootfolder in there when you try to execute the stuff underneath `#Empty the root folder`.

Change your function `Empty-SPOFolder` to

```
Function Empty-SPOFolder([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$Folder) {
    Try {
        #Process all Sub Folders of the given folder
        $SubFolders = $Folder.Folders
        $Ctx.Load($SubFolders)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        
        #Empty all subfolders
        foreach($SubDir in $SubFolders) {
            #Exclude "Forms" and Hidden folders
            Empty-Folder -Folder $SubDir
        }

        #delete all subfolders
        foreach($SubDir in $SubFolders) {
            #Exclude "Forms" and Hidden folders
        
            #Call the function recursively to empty the folder
            Empty-SPOFolder -Folder $SubDir

            #Delete the folder
            Write-Host $SubDir.UniqueId -ForegroundColor Green
            #$Ctx.Web.GetFolderById($SubDir.UniqueId).Recycle() | Out-Null
            $Ctx.Web.GetFolderById($SubDir.UniqueId).DeleteObject() | Out-Null
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Deleted Folder: $($SubDir.ServerRelativeUrl)" -ForegroundColor Green
        }

        #Empty the root folder
        # because we didn't reuse the $Folder variable, this is still a reference to the root folder
        Empty-Folder -Folder $Folder
        $Ctx = $Folder.Context
        $Files = $Folder.Files
        $Ctx.Load($Files)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Iterate through each File in the Root folder
        foreach($File in $Files) {
            #Delete the file
            Write-Host $File.Name -ForegroundColor Green
            $Folder.Files.GetByUrl($File.ServerRelativeUrl).Recycle() | Out-Null
            $Folder.Files.GetByUrl($File.ServerRelativeUrl).DeleteObject() | Out-Null
            Write-Host "Deleted File '$($File.Name)' from '$($File.ServerRelativeURL)'" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    }
    Catch {
        # use sub-expressions $() to expand the values of the properties in the string
        Write-Host "Error: $($Folder.UniqueId) - $($File.Name) " $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Also, as commented, PowerShell parses and executes code from **top to bottom**, so your functions should come **before** the main routine and **OUTSIDE** of the `Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\CS\zipp.txt | ForEach-Object {..}` loop, so:

```
# start your script with the function definitions
Function Empty-SPOFolder([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$Folder){
    ...
}
Function Empty-Folder([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$Folder) {
    ...
}

# then the main routine:
Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\CS\zipp.txt | ForEach-Object {
    ...
}
```

BTW, this line `if($_ -match $regex){` is using a `$regex` variable you did not define. Did you just omit it from the code you posted?

and I noticed you forgot to wrap object properties in a double-quoted string with `$()`. like in `"Error: $Folder.UniqueId .."`, which should be `"Error: $($Folder.UniqueId) .."`.
You need to change that in function `Empty-Folder` too.

Comment: Thanks for this but the only Issue I have now is when a folder path that I have provided have too many items inside then it give me "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceed the list view threshold"

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this since every folder I provided in the path has over 10,000+ items inside them and I'm getting that error.

Comment: @ziico Since OneDrive is actually SharePoint Online behind the scenes, it has a List View Threshold of 5000 items. It seems you cannot increase that number.. but you could try doing it all in [batches](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-get-all-items-from-large-lists-powershell-csom.html)